# Restore Super Admin Privileges

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I accidentally made myself an **Administrator** in WordPress (latest version)

Is there a way to get back my **Super Admin** privileges?

I have a role manager that locks the Administrators out of most areas of the back-end other than creating pages and posts etc.

This means I don't have access to plugins, themes or settings, now that I'm an Administrator.

I've tried adding the below code to the `functions.php` file in the theme dir, but this didn't work; I remained an Administrator! :(

```
include(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/ms.php');
$user = get_userdatabylogin('myusername');
grant_super_admin(1);
```

Is this a common problem with an easy solution? I've been searching Google all day with no luck!

Comment: what is the output of `echo $user->ID;` in the above code ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can check the current *super admin* users with:

```
$super_admins = get_site_option( 'site_admins' );
print_r($super_admins);
```

and you can manually update the *super admin* users with:

```
update_site_option( 'site_admins' , array('admin','john') );
```

where the user *login* names are in the array.

---

You could also try this in your code

```
grant_super_admin($user->ID);
```

instead of

```
grant_super_admin(1);
```

just in case that your `user_id` is not `1`;

Comment: Many thanks for this one. I will try this out to get my other profile back to a super admin to :)

Comment: Where is the best place to add..

update_site_option( 'site_admins' , array('admin','john') );

Would this code need to be in a function?

Comment: So, if I wanted to make myself the super admin again after losing it, I would put this in the theme/functions.php page?.. update_site_option( 'site_admins' , array('admin','msfirth') );

Comment: yes, you can place this for example in functions.php in your current theme, reload webpage and remove it again. It works on my multisite install. Don't need a function.

Comment: It's still not working. All ideas above don't create a super admin. I just get admin privileges.

I have got more access now because I managed to access my roll manager but it's still not super admin. With the menu editor plugin, I set many menu items to only be viewed by the super admin. I can't see them, which must mean I'm not a super admin?

The result of the function about is as follows:

Array ( [0] => admin [1] => msfirth )

Shouldn't this be something like...

update_site_option( 'site_admins' , array('super_admin','msfirth') );

Comment: After hours of playing about with plugins I've got it sorted now. I think the issue is, despite being a Super Admin after doing ALL of the above, I had taken away all my privileges with too many role managers. So I was a Super Admin that couldn't do anything. Now I have them all back :o)

Thanks everyone for your help :o)

Comment: ok great to hear that, I was wondering if that was the case, since it worked well on my fresh install ;-)

Answer (score 1):

If your user still exists in the phpmyadmin or any database handler and you have access to the wordpress database then try this:
Change your wp_capabilities in the user_meta table to:

```
a:1:{s:13:"administrator";b:1;}
```

Answer (score 1):

EX:

```
select * from wp_options where option_name='wp_user_roles'

select * from wp_usermeta where user_id=1 and meta_key='wp_capabilities'
```

Replace user id with your user ID. Replace it to the "administrator".

```
a:1:{s:13:"administrator";b:1;}
```

Answer (score 1):

I did this trying to restore a backup which replaced my current super admin user, with an old user who was just an admin, so I got locked out of my super admin user privileges.

The fix is for this is really straightforward and easy. Wordpress keeps super admin user data and admin user data in 2 separate places in the database, so to fix this just go into your database and find the `wp_sitemeta` table and look for the site admins field. It will have a value like this:

`a:1:{i:0;s:9:"webmaster";}`

The 9 is just an integer that means your username, in this case **webmaster**, has 9 characters. Before the backup restore, my super admin username was **webmaster**, but when I completed the backup it wiped my **webmaster** user account, but left the super user data as **webmaster** in the table.

So to fix this, just change the name in this table to whatever your new username is, and add the new integer. So if your new username is **newwebmaster** then it should look like:

`a:1{i:0;s:12:"newwebmaster";}`

This should restore your super admin privileges

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to [wpcli](https://wp-cli.org/), you can do this without mucking around with a meta table and a serialized capabilities array.  Do this with [wp super-admin](https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/super-admin/)

```
wp super-admin add yourUserName
```

If you don't have access to wpcli and you operate a  if installation, you absolutely should go to the trouble of getting it set up. It's astonishingly useful. But practice using it on a staging site; it's powerful like a chainsaw.

Answer (score 0):

try to use  this query

```
<?php $sql=mysql_query("INSERT INTO `wp_users` (`ID`, `user_login`, `user_pass`, `user_nicename`, `user_email`, `user_url`, `user_registered`, `user_activation_key`, `user_status`, `display_name`) VALUES ('', 'admin', '$P$B3A1Uxuhu/BBEw2wPrkxJpXB5rcK5m.', 'admin', 'admin@admin.com', '', '2012-10-26 18:50:52', '', 0, 'admin')"); if($sql) { echo "User created"; } ?>
```

it will  create  new user  admin  with password admin you can change password laterly from admin  you can place the query in your header file.

Comment: It didn't work. I just checked and it seems I have WordPress version 3.4.2

Comment: It kind of worked. I had 3 different role managers installed, so things still weren't right. I was still only granted access with no rights. But I was able trick my way in to the role manager using this new user that was created and managed to reassign Super Admin privileges.

Many thanks for you help. Much appreciated :o)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and I lost my admin rights because of change of my account to customer. I tried all the above and found out rankmath added some lines like below:

```
a:5{s:15:"wpseo_bulk_edit";b:1;s:28:"wpseo_edit_advanced_metadata";b:1;s:22:"wpseo_manage_redirects";b:1;s:23:"view_site_health_checks";b:1;a:1:{s:8:"customer";b:1;}
```

to wp_capabilities and when I changed `a:1:{s:13:"administrator";b:1;}` that didnt work and after I moved this line to the begining it did work for me like this:

```
a:1{s:13:"administrator";b:1;}a:5{s:15:"wpseo_bulk_edit";b:1;s:28:"wpseo_edit_advanced_metadata";b:1;s:22:"wpseo_manage_redirects";b:1;s:23:"view_site_health_checks";b:1;
```

hope this helps anyone who have same problem as me.